# V8: How to correctly handle microtasks?

Tags: node.js, v8

When extending V8, how involved do I/we have to be in making sure microtasks are correctly managed? V8, in general, has almost no documentation outside of the code itself, but I'm finding absolutely nothing on microtasks. Specifically, I'd like to learn about MicrotasksScope and how I need to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

You generally shouldn't need to use MicrotasksScope.

Usually you will either be using `MicrotasksPolicy::kExplicit` or `MicrotasksPolicy::kAuto`.

With a kAuto policy, any time the script evaluation stack is emptied, microtasks will be run. With kExplicit, you have to do it yourself, using `Isolate::RunMicrotasks`.

In most situations, the default (`kAuto`) will work. If you are chromium or node, using kExplicit will make more sense since you need to time your microtask queue with all the other platform stuff like timers and networking.

As for MicrotasksScope, I personally am not aware of any project that uses it, but it will behave the same as kAuto, except the microtask runs when the stack of MicrotasksScope objects empties, instead of Scripts.